# Split array keeping chosen index on center

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array like that: `[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]`. I need to split it in the half, **but chosing an index to be the new center**, i.e. always keeping the same number of elements before and after the index choosen to be the new center. Examples of the desired result:

```
// index: 1
[ 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]

// index: 3
[ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a' ]
```

I tried some things with `slice` and negative values:

```
(function splitChosingMiddle(arr, index) {
  const half = Math.floor(arr.length / 2)
  return [
    ...arr.slice(index - half),
    ...arr.slice(index, half + 1)
  ]
})([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 0)
```

But it only works if the new center is the `0` index, any other index crashs the logic. I believe I'm misunderstanding the use of negative lengths for `splice`.

Someone could help me with this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the delta between the index and the middle, slice the items using the delta to move that amount to the start/end of the array:

```js
function splitChosingMiddle(arr, index) {
  const half = Math.floor((arr.length) / 2)
  const delta = index - half

  return [
    ...arr.slice(delta, arr.length),
    ...arr.slice(0, delta)
  ]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(splitChosingMiddle([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 0)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitChosingMiddle([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitChosingMiddle([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitChosingMiddle([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitChosingMiddle([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 4)));
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'm happy I was almost there. Good approach with delta.

Answer (score 1):

try something this

```
function rotate (array, index) {
  var head = array.slice();
  var tail = head.splice(array.length - index, index);
  return tail.concat(head);
}
```

should do the trick. But try to understand it

Comment: Your ideia is interesting, but doesn't satisfy all cases: `rotate([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 3)` gives `[ 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b' ]` but I need `[ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a' ]`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, however it was the solution for my problem! Thanks for this little function!

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a CS homework problem, so I'll give a hint rather than a direct solution to save you some fun.

It looks like `index` is a number of rotations - i.e. take the last item from the list and put at the beginning (javascript has `shift` and `pop` that may be helpful).

Comment: No, my friend, it is not homework. I'm sorry if the algorithm I need seems stupid and maybe it really is, but unfortunately I could not find a simple solution on my own.